# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated mystery

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, modalviewcontroller

I've seen a number of posts on this subject, but none that leave me with a clear understanding of what is happening.

I've set up a small test involving two UIViewControllers: MainController and ModalController.

MainController has a button on it that presents a modal view controller using the following simple code:

```
ModalController *myModal = [[ModalController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:myModal animated:YES];
[myModal release];
```

Now, if I immediately dismiss this modal controller from within the same block of code, as per this next line:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

The modal view does not dismiss.

Following some suggestions on this site, I put the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` call in a separate method, which I then called with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delayedDismissal) withObject:nil 
  afterDelay:0.41];
```

This works - at least if I make the delay 0.41 or greater.  .40 or less and it doesn't work.

At this point, I'm assuming I'm dealing here a run-loop that needs to catch up with itself, for lack of a better description. It's not very stable, unfortunately.

So, for the next test, I make the delayedDismissal do nothing - it only serves to provide a delay - and re-insert the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated call back in the original block, such that my code now looks like this:

```
ModalController *myModal = [[ModalController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:myModal animated:YES];
[myModal release];
self performSelector:@selector(delayedDismissal) withObject:nil 
      afterDelay:0.41]; // to create the false delay
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

...now the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated doesn't work again, no matter how long a delay I use.

So, what is happening here?  I realize, like others, I can achieve my goal through assorted workarounds, including the use of a delegate, etc.  But I really think it would be good for everyone who encounters this issue to walk away with a thorough understanding of both the problem and the proper solution for this scenario.  Incidentally, one use case for this scenario is to present a loading screen modally where the user has no interaction with that screen; it's just being used to present information while blocking the user from taking actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is animating, thus as long as it is animating calling dismiss won't work.

Also in the second thing you tried, you are calling a "delay" but what you are actually doing is saying the following: "Ok, here  is this cute method, can you execute that 0.41 seconds later? thanks, in the mean time, call this method.."

Dismissing a modal view controller should be done through the userinterface, by clicking a button, so why are you trying this in the first place?

Comment: First, thanks for the clarification on my second experiment.  My real end-goal is to use a modal form to convey information about a long-running synchronization in a disaster-recovery scenario (i.e. where the application isn't usable until the recovery synch is complete).  I have my reasons for choosing a modal form over a UIAlertView or UIActionSheet, but the point is, there will be no user interaction with the modal form.  The application itself must close said form.  The truth is, I'll be doing this in delegate method, so I doubt I'll have a problem.  But when I set up this small...

Comment: ...experiment, I was surprised to see this behavior.  Regarding your comment of "dismissing a modal view controller should be done through the user interface, by clicking a button", how else would you suggest I achieve my goal?  I have too much information to convey to place in a UIAlertView or a UIActionSheet, and I don't want the user to suffer the frustration of trying to interact with an application that's been corrupted, so what are my other options during such a recovery?

Comment: @wayne An UIAlertView requires a user action before it is dismissed as well right? Then implemented such a button on your modalview as well! and I personally don't think you should ever display so much data to an iphone user, but then again I don't know the context.

Comment: @Antwan  Normally I'd never display so much information to a user or block the user from interacting with the application, but this is, as I say, a disaster recovery scenario servicing a technical clientele - they want to see the info.  So, while I have placed a Cancel button on the modal form, I was hoping, in the event of a successful recovery, to simply gracefully close the modal form programmatically from the main controller.  Which brings me back to my original question...surely there must be a way to do this! :)

Comment: @Wayne yes, and the way is to notify your other controllers whenever the modal view controller is done animating and ready to go, because then you can also gracefully close it, otherwise a user would see an interrupted animation which is ugly -- don't ask me how though, probably something in - (void)viewDidAppear but you would have to test that yourself.

Comment: @Antwan Okay, thanks for all the help/advice.  I'll mark this as answered because you've given me sufficient information to proceed.